# Can't install latest blender on windows

Tags: windows, installation

- I go to the blender website
- Select the 64 bit US instillation for my Windows 7 Desktop Computer.
- After downloading I open the Blender Set Up Wizard and I am given three options: Change/Repair/Remove
- I have tried to Change and Repair but once completed if I open Blender the Update has not been installed and the blender is still the older version.
- I am considering uninstalling everything and trying again but I have several projects on the current blender and I can't risk loosing them

Can anyone help explain to me what steps I can take to safely install and apply the latest version of blender. I have version 2.66a and I'm trying to get the latest 2.76b.

*Any help would be greatly appreciated!*

Comment: i have windows xp and when i installed its give error and when i want to uninstall its giving the error code 2753. How to install and which version is suitable for xp and latest also

Comment: Have you tried installing a .zip file of blender?

Answer (score 1):

From the *manual*:

Download the `.zip` or `.exe` for your architecture (64bit is preferable if your machine supports it).

The .exe will run an installer to choose where to place Blender and to configure MS-Windows to have an entry on the menu and to open .blend files with Blender. Administrator rights are needed to install Blender on your system.

**Note:**
With `.zip` you have to manually extract Blender to the desired folder, where you can double-click the executable to run Blender.

There is no installer to place Blender on the menu, but there is also no need for administrator rights. With this option it is possible to have multiple versions of Blender without conflicting, as they are not actually installed on the system.

https://www.blender.org/manual/getting_started/installing_blender/windows.html

Comment: I'm sorry.. I don't understand? Any way to get a brief run down for someone not particularly computer savvy?

Comment: There's no .exe option? I only see Installer (.msi) and .Zip as options... I'm confused.

Comment: Wait, I think I figured it out. Thank you for your response

Answer (score -1):

I know just delete Blender and download it again. You should have latest version then. If not then just wait until tomorrow and you should download it again and Done you have it.

Comment: Why waiting until tomorrow?